# Is there any other way to use the same layout with different attributes multiple times in Android Studio, except DataBinding?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, include

> I have the following Layout named `sample_layout.xml` and I want to
>   use it multiple times but **each time with a few changes**.
>
> ```
> <LinearLayout 
>     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:orientation="vertical"
>     android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">
>
>     <RelativeLayout
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="110dp"
>     android:background="@drawable/full_panel_blue"
>     android:padding="10dp"
>     android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">
>
>     <ImageView
>         android:layout_width="120dp"
>         android:layout_height="120dp"
>         android:src="@mipmap/first_icon" />
>
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:layout_width="350dp"
>         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>         android:gravity="end"
>         android:orientation="vertical">
>
>         <TextView
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:textColor="@color/my_white"
>             android:text="4000000"
>             android:textSize="50sp"
>             android:gravity="end"/>
>
>         <TextView
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="match_parent"
>             android:gravity="end"
>             android:textColor="@color/my_white"
>             android:textSize="20sp"
>             android:text="Sample text" />
>
>     </LinearLayout>
>
>     </RelativeLayout>
>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```
>
> Lower is the layout where it will be included multiple times
>
> ```
> <LinearLayout
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:orientation="vertical">
>
>     <include layout="@layout/sample_layout"/>
>     <include layout="@layout/sample_layout"/>
>     <include layout="@layout/sample_layout"/>
>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```
>
> So, I want to include it first time just as it is, but the second time
>   instead of the `@drawable/full_blue_panel`, I want to use another
>   drawable (`@drawable/red_w_transparency`). And also for the
>   `ImageView` I want to use another `src` for the icon second time, and
>   another one the third time. Maybe different text in the `TextView`
>   each time and so on for any of the previously created attributes. I
>   already tried something with DataBinding but I don't think it is
>   exactly suitable for this. Is there any other way to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, I solve this sort of problem by creating a custom `View` subclass. The basics are covered here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#compound

The short version is that you define some custom attributes that affect the pieces you want to change, then create a `View` subclass implementation that reads those attributes to modify its view hierarchy.

In your posted example, you have these relevant points:

- The root is a `LinearLayout`
- You want to change the `RelativeLayout` background
- You want to change the `ImageView` src
- You want to change the `TextView` text

You could create these attributes in your `attrs.xml`:

```
<declare-styleable name="MyCompoundComponent">
    <attr name="background"/>
    <attr name="imageSrc"/>
    <attr name="primaryText"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

Next, you create your view class. Since your original layout's root was `LinearLayout`, we'll derive from that:

```
public class MyCompoundComponent extends LinearLayout {

    public MyCompoundComponent(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyCompoundComponent);
        // read your attributes
        a.recycle();

        inflate(context, R.layout.my_compound_component, this);

        // find your views, use your attributes to modify them
    }
}
```

And, of course, you need a layout. You can just use the one you posted above, except you'd change the root element to `<merge>` now that you're inflating it inside of a `LinearLayout`.

With all that in place, you can use this view in your other layouts just like any other view:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.example.stackoverflow.MyCompoundComponent
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:background="@color/blue"
        app:imageSrc="@drawable/image1"
        app:primaryText="@string/text1"/>

    <com.example.stackoverflow.MyCompoundComponent
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:background="@color/red"
        app:imageSrc="@drawable/image2"
        app:primaryText="@string/text2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: ok, I have done all that, but still I dont see how it would know which `imageSrc` will be changed in the custom layout since there are two `ImageView`, or how will it know which text has to be changed since there are more in the custom view (and they are nested)

Comment: Create multiple attributes. You can use any name you'd like, maybe `<attr name="imageSrc1"/>` and `<attr name="imageSrc2"/>`, or `<attr name="background"/>` vs `<attr name="foreground"/>` etc. Then you can get those in the code and assign them to the right views.